# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] always give me static link

Tags: magento

I am developing ecommerce using magento now. But, when I want to use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], it's always give me this link /SKIN/ADMINHTML/DEFAULT/DEFAULT/xxxx/CSS/JQUERY.UI.ACCORDION.CSS

Where I can set $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ? or any other way for this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current request URL you should use:

```
Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
```

or to get the base url defined on database:

```
Mage::getBaseUrl();
```

Comment: Yeah, I use it too (getCurrentUrl()). But this way give same result.

Comment: in the getCurrentUrl function there is this code $request->getServer('REQUEST_URI');

so, I think,the problem is with REQUEST_URI